# How to refactor Swift API call to use Swift 5.5 async/await?

Tags: swift, macos, async-await, swiftui

I want to refactor some API calls to use Swift 5.5's new async/await in my SwiftUI project.  However, it's unclear to me how to replace or accomodate the completions.

Here's an example function which I want to refactor:

```swift
 static func getBooks(completion: @escaping ([Book]?) -> Void) {
    let request = getRequest(suffix: "books")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            fatalError("Error: \(error)")
        }
        if let data = data {
            if let books = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Book].self, from: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("books.count: \(books.count)")
                    completion(books)
                }
                return
            } else {
                fatalError("Unable to decode JSON")
            }
        } else {
            fatalError("Data is nil")
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I beleve the new function signature would look something like this:

```swift
static func getBooks() async throws -> ([Book]?) {
   // ...
}
```

However, I have no idea what to do with the `URLSession.shared.dataTask`, `DispatchQueue.main.async` and `completion`, etc.

Anyone know what the new function body should look like?

Thanks

Comment: [Meet async await](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132) about minute 26:59

Comment: Watch through [WWDC 2021 – Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/). It's an entire hour code-along video that takes you step by step through how to progressively migrate parts of an app. The parts they chose to replace have a nice variety of real-world patterns to them, so it's a reallllllly great/applicable video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
func getBooks() async throws -> [Book] {
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    return try JSONDecoder().decode([Book].self, from: data)
}
```

This will throw if the request fails, and if the response cannot be decoded. Since the function is marked as throwing, then the calling function has to handle the raised errors.

You don't need to declare the returned `[Book]` to be optional, because it will either return an honest array, or throw an error.

In your additional code, you had to call your completion handler on the main queue, because you were calling it from within the completion block of the request. You don't need to do that here.